# Unchecking a checkbox with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a model that renders a list of checkboxes.  When I check one box I would like any other checked boxes to become unchecked.  The below code seems to iterate fine, but the html is not reflecting the changes. What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in commonOrders">
                            <td>{{x.ProductName}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.ProductItemCode}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.ProductSize}}</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" 
                                       ng-click="updateCommonProduct(x)" 
                                       ng-checked="x.IsChecked"/></td>
                        </tr>
```

angular/javascript:

```
$scope.updateCommonProduct = function(product) {

    // uncheck non-selected common orders
    angular.forEach($scope.commonOrders, function(value, key) {
        if (value.ProductItemCode !== product.ProductItemCode) {
            value.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }, $scope.commonOrders);



};
```

Comment: Can you just use radio buttons?

Comment: can you post a Plunkr/JsFiddle ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You should use `ngModel` & `ngChange`:

- `ngModel` creates a two-way binding between the model and the DOM.
- `ngChange` triggers an event when a model gets change.

---

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lrQnA6JrvlsirqK8QGaE?p=preview

**Template:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in commonOrders">
   <td>{{x.ProductName}}</td>
   <td>{{x.ProductItemCode}}</td>
   <td>{{x.ProductSize}}</td>
   <td>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-change="check(x)" ng-model="x.isChecked"/>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

**Controller method:**

```
$scope.check = function(current) {
  angular.forEach($scope.commonOrders, function(product) {
    if(product !== current) {
      product.isChecked = false;  
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.  I don't know why this question got marked down. Mark downs with out explanation don't help me or anyone else with the same problem viewing this.  For the record, I was able to leave my code exactly the same by replacing ng-click with ng-change and ng-checked with ng-model.